# iOS "linker command failed with exit code 1" error when adding GoogleMaps pod

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods

Adding Crashlytics to an existing project I am working on (Objective-C) made me update some of the Google pods, up until that moment everything worked fine, after I've managed to integrate Crashlytics I've started receiving this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_UIPointerShape", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in GoogleMaps
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_UIPointerStyle", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in GoogleMaps
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

Here is my podfile:

[image]

And here's how it used to be before the changes:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually I've went to prev commit and checked the version of GooglePlaces and GooleMaps (which was 3.7.0) and have been updated to 3.9.0.
I've limited the version to 3.7.0 (pod 'GoogleMaps', '~>3.7.0' & pod 'GooglePlaces', '~>3.7.0') and it worked

Comment: Thanks. I came across same issue. And it's fine to downgrade Library Version.

Answer (score 5):

According to this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63530 it is probably caused by Google Maps 3.10 not supporting Xcode version lower than 11.4.

I can confirm, that

```
pod 'GoogleMaps', '<3.10'
```

fixes the build for me.